# When does aPerson.firstname and aPerson.lastname actually change in this code snippet?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm going through some JavaScript koans to learn the language syntax and I'm confused by this set of tests:

```
it("should know that variables inside a constructor and constructor args are private", function () {
    function Person(firstname, lastname)
    {
      var fullName = firstname + " " + lastname;

      this.getFirstName = function () { return firstname; };
      this.getLastName = function () { return lastname; };
      this.getFullName = function () { return fullName; };
    }
    var aPerson = new Person ("John", "Smith");

    aPerson.firstname = "Penny";
    aPerson.lastname = "Andrews";
    aPerson.fullName = "Penny Andrews";

    expect(aPerson.getFirstName()).toBe("John");
    expect(aPerson.getLastName()).toBe("Smith");
    expect(aPerson.getFullName()).toBe("John Smith");

    aPerson.getFullName = function () {
      return aPerson.lastname + ", " + aPerson.firstname;
    };

    expect(aPerson.getFullName()).toBe("Andrews, Penny");
  });
```

I get that the variables inside a constructor are private, and that's why "John Smith" still prints when calling getFullName() even after attempting to set aPerson.firstname, lastname, and fullName. But then a function is created called getFullName(), and then after that calling the function "Andrews, Penny" prints.

I would have expected "Smith, John" to print since this new function was created after the "failed" attempt to set firstname to "Penny" and lastname to "Andrews". Why does "Andrews, Penny" print?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't that depend on what `it()`, `expect()` and `toBe()` actually do? Did you miss some code?

Comment: You pretty much nailed it when you said that they were "private". With no setters what else can you expect?

Comment: Uh, yes, those scoped variables are private. No function other than those defined inside the constructor will be able to access them. This doesn't change if the privileged method is overwritten by a different one. Notice also that the overriding function does specifically access the `aPerson` properties and not any variables from a scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is the **[`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)**; `var aPerson = new Person ("John", "Smith")` creates a new `Person`, passing in `John` and `Smith` as the names used by the `Person` function, and assigning the new instance of the function to the variable `aPerson`.

Note the `var fullName = firstname + " " + lastname` inside of the `Person` function. This takes whatever is passed through as the function parameter at the time the `Person` function is called. At this point, `this.getFullName` will be equal to `John Smith`.

When you run `aPerson.firstname = "Penny"`
this only updates the **new** instance of the `Person`; it doesn't modify the original `Person` function. When you call `aPerson.getFirstName()`, the `getFirstName()` method returns what was originally set as `firstname` for **`Person`** (John), not what has been set for the new instance `aPerson` (Penny).

As such, the first time you call `aPerson.getFullName()`, the name is `John Smith`.

Your new function `aPerson.getFullName = function () { }` returns `aPerson.lastname + ", " + aPerson.firstname`. Unlike the previous function, this takes the last and first name from the **new** instance of `Person` (Penny Andrews).

As such, the second time you call `aPerson.getFullName()`, the name is `Penny Andrews`.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand this:

```
function Person(firstname, lastname)
{
  var fullName = firstname + " " + lastname;
  ...
}

var aPerson = new Person ("John", "Smith");
```

Here, the only thing you created was an object with only methods on it, not even attributes, like firstname, lastname. (Parameters and variables declared with var aren't attached to your object)

So your object aPerson is like this:

```
{
    getFirstName: function(), // => John
    getLastName: function(), // => Smith
    getFullName: function() // => John Smith
}
```

Then:

```
aPerson.firstname = "Penny";
aPerson.lastname = "Andrews";
aPerson.fullName = "Penny Andrews";
```

You assigned on your aPerson object new attributes. So, it becomes like this:

```
{
    firstname: "Penny",
    lastname: "Andrews",
    fullName: "Penny Andrews",
    getFirstName: function(), // => John
    getLastName: function(), // => Smith
    getFullName: function() // => John Smith
}
```

Next, you overriding getFullName with this:

```
aPerson.getFullName = function () {
    return aPerson.lastname + ", " + aPerson.firstname;
};
```

As your can see, you use these new attributes.

Now, you should be able to understand your result.
If you do the replacement, you get this:

```
aPerson.getFullName = function () {
    return aPerson.lastname + ", " + aPerson.firstname;
    //     Andrews             ,     Penny
};
```

And voilà ! It's why you get your result ;)